# Minimum value of $a\log(bc) + bc \log(a) $

Tags: number-theory

Conjecture on the Minimum value of $a\log(bc) + bc \log(a)$.

Conjecture:
Given three successive odd primes, the value of the above expression is minimum if the largest of the three odd primes is set as a, and the remaining two are set as b and c.

Here is a solution sent to me by a kind and very famous mathematician:

The rule you observed “ pick the largest of a, b, c holds as soon as a, b, c are relatively close and not too small, which holds for successive odd primes. For the three, (x, y)= (a, bc), (b, ca) or (c, ab) you have the same value of xy. For X=log x, Y=log y , we have the same value for X+Y=S= log (abc) For X + Y= fixed S, not too small you consider: (e^X).Y+ X.(e^Y) (where X+Y=S) As a function of X in [0.S], the graph of this function looks like:(symmetrical in X<->S-X) and you are near X~S/3, there it is decreasing. Hence your rule.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean $a\log(bc)+bc\log(a)$?

Comment: yes Tom, thanks for the correction.

Comment: just making sure, log is the base 10 log ?

Comment: Base doesn't matter (as long as the base is $>1$) since the above can be written as $\log(b^ac^aa^{bc})$. So you are really trying to minimize $b^ac^aa^{bc}$. @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: So... you are asking if $b, c < a$ to prove $a \log bc + bc \log a$ is less than either $b\log ac + ac \log b$ or $c\log ab + ab \log c$?

Comment: that is the conjecture to be proven, given three successive odd primes

Comment: Let $x=a$, $y=bc$, and you are trying to minimize $\log(y^xx^y)$.

Comment: Let $n=abc$; then the quantity in question is $a(\log n-\log a) + n\frac{\log a}a$. So let $f(x) = x(\log n-\log x) + n\frac{\log x}x$ and show that $f(x)$ is decreasing, at least when $x$ is near $n^{1/3}$.

Comment: The property is verified for any triple $(n+3,\;n+4,\;n+5)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. To a greater extent is true for number with larger distance the one from the other such as odd numbers, prime numbers etc

Comment: The rule you observed  “ pick the largest of a, b, c holds as soon as a, b, c are relatively close and not too small, which holds for successive odd primes.
For the three, (x, y)= (a, bc), (b, ca) or (c, ab) you have the same value of xy. For X=log x, Y=log y , we have the same value for X+Y=S=  log (abc)
For X + Y= fixed S, not too small you consider:
(e^X).Y+ X.(e^Y)                                                      (where X+Y=S)
As a function of X in [0.S], the graph of this function looks like:(symmetrical in X<->S-X) and you are near X~S/3, there it is decreasing. Hence your rule.

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ GregMartin

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ alex.jordan

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ flea blood

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ Raffaele

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ ThomasAndrews

Comment: Thank you all. I received a solution from a kind and renowned mathematician pasted above and figure is posted in the main question. @ RoddyMacPhee